# Pagination not working - FrontPage

Tags: functions, shortcode, paginate-links

I'm trying to add pagination through function.php. No Output! What I'm missing?

```
function simpleblog() {
    $query = 'posts_per_page=6';
    $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
    // The Loop...
    if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
            $queryObject->the_post();
            //the_title();
            //the_content();
            get_template_part( 'content' );
            echo '<hr class="empty-space-hr">';
        }
    } else {
        //no post found
    }

        echo'<div class="pagination">';
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Newer Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Older Posts', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
        echo '</div>';
    
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_shortcode( 'simpleblog', 'simpleblog' );
```

Comment: That `$query->max_num_pages` should be `$queryObject->max_num_pages`..

Comment: If it's a shortcode you might need to use an output buffer. Does the output appear in thee page source but in the wrong place?

Comment: to @SallyCJ : It's working(`$queryObject`), but the pagination not working properly. 
For instance, if I click on the 2nd or 3rd or whatever page number, it's redirecting me to the same page (front page).

Comment: shortcodes must return their content, not `echo` it, you will need output buffers to make this work. Shortcodes that `echo` directly will break other shortcodes, appear in the wrong order, don't work in nested shortcodes, as well as a lot of other problems

Comment: @ChinmayRajyaguru so did my answer help, or is the pagination working properly now? And if any of the current answers answered the question, please consider "accepting" (just tick the check-mark next to) that answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this on archive pages. If you are trying to use it elsewhere then that might be a cause of the issue.

```
if ( ! function_exists( '_s_pagination_links' ) ) :
/**
 * Numbered pagination
 */
function _s_pagination_links() {
    global $wp_query;

    $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){
        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => 'page/%#%',
            'type'      => 'list',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
        ));
    }
}
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the comments you said:

> if I click on the 2nd or 3rd or whatever page number, it's redirecting
> me to the same page (front page)

And that's because your query args (`$query`) is missing the [`paged` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) which is needed for paginating the posts.

So make sure to add that arg to your query. E.g. using array:

```php
$query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged'          => get_query_var( 'page' ),
);
```

Note that I assumed you are actually using a [static front page](https://wordpress.org/support/article/creating-a-static-front-page/), hence I used `get_query_var( 'page' )` and not `get_query_var( 'paged' )` (note the `page` vs `paged` — in the `$query` though, it *is* `paged`).

So you should also use that with `paginate_links()`:

```php
echo paginate_links( array(
    ... your args.
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'page' ) ), // use 'page' and not 'paged'
    ... your args.
) );
```

BTW, in the question, (it seemed like) you made a typo: That `$query->max_num_pages` should be `$queryObject->max_num_pages`.

And if you're *not* actually using a static front page, then you should, to avoid 404 errors with the pagination due to a conflict with the *main* WordPress query.

### Update

(Sorry, I didn't really notice the `add_shortcode()` call in your code.)

> No Output! What I'm missing?

As pointed in the comments, shortcodes must return the final output and not echoed, and that a shortcode function should not echo anything else. Otherwise, the output would be misplaced in the post content, and causes a JSON error in the REST API response and results in a failure in saving the post via the Gutenberg/block editor. And those are just two sample issues that could happen.

So if your shortcode uses a complex HTML markup, you could use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php); otherwise, just store the output in a variable and then return it. Simplified example:

```php
// Using output buffering:
function simpleblog() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
        some complex HTML
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

// Storing to a variable:
function simpleblog() {
    $output = '';

    // ... your code here; no 'echo' calls.
    $output .= 'foo bar';

    return $output;
}
```

### Further Reading

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API